# Cascading/Inherited/Shared Rails configuration environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

My staging and production environment Rails configuration are 99% the same with just a few things set differently (e.g. the log level), and I'd really like to eliminate the duplication between the two environment files.

For example, I have something like this:

```
# config/environments/staging.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=31536000"
  config.log_level = :debug
  # ...
end

# config/environments/production.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=31536000"
  config.log_level = :info
  # ...
end
```

Any recommendations on the best way to create a shared configuration that doesn't also affect my development environment?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In my projects, I have 3 production-like environments so I have a file called shared_production.rb under `config/environments` where I put the common configuration

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
  #more shared configs
end
```

And then in each environment specific config file (production.rb, staging.rb, testing.rb) I do

```
require File.expand_path('../shared_production', __FILE__)
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.log_level = :debug
  #more environment specific configs
end
```

Comment: DHH has a similar approach with a lot more detail in http://signalvnoise.com/posts/3535-beyond-the-default-rails-environments